# On git how to remove files from staging area and also modify the working directory

Tags: git

on git if after a git status I have:

```
Changes to be commited:
modified: index.html
Changes not staged for commit:
modified: myScripts.js
```

Which command should be executed to remove all files from the staging area and also modify the working directory to match the most recent commit?

Comment: If you mean discarding all the modifications you've made, then just checkout to the latest commit. `git checkout` probably

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+files+from+staging